# How can I extract an actual URL from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string like this

```
let content = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
```

Now I want to write a regex what will give me only the actual domain with the protocol

example: from content, I should get only **"https://stackoverflow.com"**

Comment: regexp `/^http[s]?://[^/]+/`

Comment: Pass it to the URL constructor and grab the hostname property...

Comment: `const url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')` - See at [URL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) for the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write a regex when the ability to parse URLs already exist.

> [MDN: Web technology for developers > See Web APIs > URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```js
const url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");

console.log(`${url.origin}`);                    // Includes port
console.log(`${url.protocol}//${url.hostname}`); // Alternatively...
```

Comment: what about `url.origin`?

Comment: @TKoL Good point.